# SAS: using first. and last. to process a date range

Tags: sas

I am trying to go through a list of dates and keep only the date range for dates that 5 or more occurrences and delete all others. The example I have is:

```
data test;
     input dt dt2;
     format dt dt2 date9.;
     datalines;
     20000 20001
     20000 20002
     20000 20003
     21000 21001
     21000 21002
     21000 21003
     21000 21004
     21000 21005
     ;
run;

proc sort data = test;
     by dt dt2;
run;

data check;
    set test;
    by dt dt2;
    format dt dt2 date9.;
    if last.dt = first.dt then
        if abs(last.dt2 - first.dt) < 5 then delete;
run;
```

What I want returned is just one entry, if possible, but I would be happy with the entire appropriate range as well. 
The one entry would be a table that has:

```
 start_dt end_dt
 21000    21005
```

The appropriate range is:

```
     21000 21001
     21000 21002
     21000 21003
     21000 21004
     21000 21005
```

My code doesn't work as desired, and I am not sure what changes I need to make.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`last.dt2` and `first.dt` are flags and can have value in (0,1), so condition `abs(last.dt2 - first.dt) < 5` is always true.
Use counter variable to count records in group instead:

```
data check(drop= count);
    length count 8;
    count=0;
    do until(last.dt);
        set test;
        by dt dt2;
        format dt dt2 date9.;
        count = count+1;
        if last.dt and count>=5 then output;
    end;
run;
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you are looking to use the last.dt2 and the first.dt within your delete function so I have turned it around to create your desired output:

```
data check2;
set test;
    by dt ;
    format dt dt2 date9.;
    if last.dt then do;
        if abs(dt2 - dt) >= 5 then output;
    end;
run;
```

Of course, this will only work if your file is sorted on dt and dt2.

Hope this helps.